# How can I do pattern matching on tuple constructors (OCaml)

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have the following types:

```
type letter = A | B | C | D (*...*)
type mix = Char of letter | Mix of (mix * int) list
```

I want to make a function, which counts the number of occuriencies of a `letter` in a `mix`, but struggling to do the pattern matching right.

```
let rec count_char letter mix = match mix with
    | Char l -> (*...*)
    | Mix (m, i) -> (*...*)
```

I am getting this error

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
       (mix * int) list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it's a tuple, it's that it is a *list* of tuples that you're trying to match against a single tuple. `Mix ((m, i) :: _)` will work, but will of course result in a partial match unless you also have a branch that matches the empty list.

Comment: With `Mix ((m, i) :: _)` i can access the first tuple, but how do I call the function `count_char` recursively on the rest of the list?

Comment: replace `_` with an identifier like `rest`, then call `count_char letter rest`. `_` is called the wildcard pattern, and will match anything but then just ignore it. Using an identifier will also match anything, but will bind it to the identifier name, in this case `rest`.

Comment: Wouldn't `rest` be a list? This pattern expect a `mix`. Not sure if this is correct, can't test it atm

Comment: Right, it is. So I guess you'll have to fold the the list, then call count_char on every `mix` inside the list.